# Advanced search in realm iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, realm

I want to perform a search on an entity I have (using `realm-cocoa`)
For example:

```
@interface Person : RLMObject
@property NSString *firstName;
@property NSString *lastName;
@property NSString *nickName;
@end
```

I have a `UIViewController` that holds a `UITableView` that is displaying a list of all the `Person` entities, I also have a `UISearchBar` above the table.

Now,
What I want is when a user enters certain text in the search bar, to search if this text is contained **in any of my properties**, also, I want to sort the results based on relevance.

For example, if have have a person named Sandro and another named Alessandro, when i'm searching for the text 'Sandro' I want to see the person named Sandro first, if i search 'San' I want to sort alphabetically (meaning Alessandro will be first).

I have not found a method in `realm` that can help me achieve this.

Comment: Answer updated with Objective-C solution

Answer (score 0):

In `Objective-C` you need to declare a `RLMResult` object to get the array of Person objects and using the `sortedResultUsingKeyPath` method you can sort your result

**Try with this**

**In Objective-C**

```
RLMRealm * realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm transactionWithBlock:^{
    [realm addObject:[Person personWithFirstName:@"Reinier"]];
    [realm addObject:[Person personWithFirstName:@"Test"]];
}];

NSString * searchValue = @"Re";

//Here we search for objects that containts in the firstName the value of searchValue string
RLMResults * result2 = [[Person objectsWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName CONTAINS %@",searchValue]] sortedResultsUsingKeyPath:@"firstName"  ascending:true];
NSMutableArray * arrayOfPerson = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i< [result2 count];i++)
{
    [arrayOfPerson addObject:[result2 objectAtIndex:i]];
}

NSLog(@"%@",arrayOfPerson);
```

**this is in Swift**

```
yourArrayOfPersons = realm?.objects(Person.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "firstName")
```

Comment: I am aware of that method, however, it will not help me in my case. I am not looking to sort by keyPath, but rather by relevance to a certain search term.

Comment: Check my answer again @NaorLevi and let me know

Comment: I am aware that in the example you gave the sorting will be correct, however, if we use the example I gave in the question, your answer will not work - if my Person will contain "Sandro" and "Alessandro" instead of "Reinier" and "Test", and `searchTerm` will be "Sandro" I would like to see "Sandro" before "Alessandro". With your answer I will see "Alessandro" first.

Comment: You want your result ordered by similitude with your search is that what you want? @NaorLevi